# Group list into elements with same value

Tags: c#, linq

This is my `Result` class:

```
public class Result
{
    public DateTime Checked { get; set; }
    public bool IsWorking { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have theese results in list:

```
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
```

I want to split them as following:

```
// group 1
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;

// group 2
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;

// group 3
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;

// group 4
Date: ..., IsWorking = false;

// group 5
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
Date: ..., IsWorking = true;
```

I've managed something like this:

```
public static List<List<T>> SplitByEqualProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inputs, string property)
{
    List<List<T>> temp = new List<List<T>>();
    temp.Add(new List<T>());

    object previousSelector = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); i++)
    {
        var current = inputs.ElementAt(i);
        Type t = current.GetType();
        PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(property);
        object currentSelector = prop.GetValue(current);

        if (previousSelector == null)
        {
            temp.LastOrDefault().Add(current);
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentSelector.Equals(previousSelector))
            {
                temp.LastOrDefault().Add(current);
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Add(new List<T>() { current });
            }
        }

        previousSelector = currentSelector;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

And this is working, but I don't like the code. Expecially part with `string property`. How can I improve that?

Answer (score 5):

You've tagged this [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) so you're clearly aware of Linq, but this is not a Linq-like approach. The closest approximation in Linq is [`GroupBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__), so that can serve as a model:

1. Instead of `string property` take `Func<TSource, TKey>`.
2. Instead of `List<List<T>>` (which, apart from anything else, violates the principle of coding to the interface instead of the implementation) return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` (or, if you don't care about the value itself, `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>>`).

Also, in Linq style, favour lazy implementation with `yield return`.

I would advise you to rewrite from scratch with those principles in mind.

---

But I must address one major problem in this code, lest you repeat it in the rewrite:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); i++)
>     {
>         var current = inputs.ElementAt(i);
> ```

This is absolutely the wrong way to iterate over an `IEnumerable`. The right way is

```
    foreach (var current in inputs)
    {
```

Otherwise if `inputs` is lazy you do far more work than necessary, and potentially execute side-effects more times than you might expect.

---

Also,

> ```
>     if (previousSelector == null)
> ```

is problematic. What if this method is used with objects which actually have `null` as a value of the relevant property? I think the best approach is to use the current `IGrouping`: either initialise that to `null` and test whether it's null, or initialise it to a grouping with key `default(T)` and replace the special case with a special case which doesn't return an empty grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `Linq` approach that allows you to perform an *analytical function* on a collection, given a *order by* clause, and a *predicate* to determine whether the current item and the previous item (*analytical lag*) are in the same group. It can be extended to also take into account a *partition*, but that's out of scope to serve your purpose.

This is a more generalized approach for the OP's *SplitByEqualProperty* method. I have augmented the problem into not just *equal property check*, but any kind of property check. Because of this generalization, I opt to use IEnumerable over IGrouping.

**Usage**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var results = new List<Result> 
        {
            Create("JAN", true), Create("FEB", true),
            Create("MAR", false),
            Create("APR", true),
            Create("MAY", false), Create("JUN", false), Create("JUL", false),
            Create("AUG", true),
            Create("SEP", true), Create("OCT", true),
            Create("NOV", false), Create("DEC", false),
        };

        var grouped = results.JoinBy(
            x => x.Checked, 
            x => x.IsWorking, 
            (previous, current) => previous == current);
    }

    internal static Result Create(string month, bool isWorking) {
        return new Result {
            Checked = DateTime.ParseExact("2019" + month + "01", "yyyyMMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            IsWorking = isWorking
        };
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public DateTime Checked { get; set; }
        public bool IsWorking { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Linq**

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> JoinBy<TSource, TOrderKey, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TOrderKey> orderBy,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TKey, TKey, bool> join) {
        var results = new List<List<TSource>>();
        var orderedSource = new List<TSource>(source).OrderBy(orderBy).ToArray();

        if (orderedSource.Length > 0) {
            var group = new List<TSource> { orderedSource[0] };
            results.Add(group);
            if (orderedSource.Length > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < orderedSource.Length; i++) {
                    var lag = orderedSource[i - 1];
                    var current = orderedSource[i];
                    if (join(keySelector(lag), keySelector(current))) {
                        group.Add(current);
                    }
                    else {
                        group = new List<TSource> { current };
                        results.Add(group);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is about grouping, I think it would be better if the return value of `JoinBy` was `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`. Oh, one more thing, you have presented an alternative version without mentioning anything in particular about OP's code... On Code Review this is _usually_ required...

Comment: @t3ch0t Thanks for the tip about community guidelines. About the Grouping vs Enumerable dilemma: my code isn't necessarely a grouped-by-key collection, instead the 'join' clause can also group on any function between comparing two adjacent keys.